# Loop through a range of cells downwards until blank cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Here is my for loop attempt:

```vb
Sub test()

    Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("do not open!").Range("F1"))
        If UI.ComboBoxSource <> ActiveCell Then
            MsgBox "This procedure already exhists. Please click on update summary. "
        Else
        End If
        Worksheets("do not open!").Range("F1").Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

End Sub
```

I am trying to loop through a range of cells (F1 downwards in this case until blank cell), and applying the if statement to compare if the values match.
If the values match, I want the loop to continue till the end.
If there is a mismatch, I want the `MsgBox` to appear and stop the loop.

This is what I tried to do:

```vb
Sub check_procedures()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngF As Range
  
    Set ws = Worksheets("do not open!")
    Set rngF = ws.Range("F1")
   
    Do Until rngF.Value = ""
        If UI.ComboBoxSource = rngF.Value Then
            MsgBox "This procedure already exhists. Please click on Update Summary. "
            Exit Sub
        Else
        End If
        
        Set rngF = rngF.Offset(1)
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, it seems that the issue in your code is your `Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("do not open!").Range("F1"))` never checks a different range. In your loop you are selecting the next row down, but you are never changing the conditional in your `Do Until` loop. You should use `Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("do not open!").ActiveCell)`, but there are certainly better ways to achieve what you seem to be doing (for example, selecting each cell is slow). As Scott said, you also want to change the later line to `Worksheets("do not open!").ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select`

Comment: And make sure you select `Worksheets("do not open!").Range("F1").Select` before your loop.

Comment: Don't `select` on worksheet `do not open!` if you don't want that sheet to be active (probably I think that fails anyway if you don't activate the sheet first, before you try to select a cell on it...)

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Likely you don't need to loop. What is the actual end goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way. Selecting, activating only consumes Excel resources, without bringing any benefit:

```
Sub test()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, rngF As Range
  
  Set ws = Worksheets("do not open!")
  Set rngF = ws.Range("F1")
   
   Do Until rngF.Value = ""
         If UI.ComboBoxSource <> rngF.Value Then
            MsgBox "This procedure already exhists. Please click on update summary. "
         Else 
            'do something...
         End If
         Set rngF = rngF.Offset(1)
  Loop

End Sub
```

But the code looks strange as logic. It will send a lot of messages. What to be done when `UI.ComboBoxSource = rngF.Value`? Should all cell values in F:F be equal with `UI.ComboBoxSource` and only by accident one, or two will not be? If only one, you should place `Exit Do` after, to make the code faster, not iterating up to the first empty cel...

Comment: Thank you very much, this is extremely helpful! Basically what I am trying to achieve is...if the match is met then keep going trough the loop...if there is a mismatch, I want to show the MsgBox and then end the loop. In addition(You dont have to answer this) I was wondering if you knew how to then loop for multiple columns? like to apply this to Column F,G,H? Thanks again for all your help. Happy to give you full score.

Comment: @King Not sure I can get you... What "loop for multiple columns" should mean? Do you want comparing `UI.ComboBoxSource` with values of all the mentioned/necessary columns? Do you want comparing three such combo values with the mentioned columns? I am really not able to understand what you want saying...